# How to enchant Minecraft sticks and what are the enchantments?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How to enchant Minecraft  Sticks? Is it possible at all?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you enchant a stick?

Comment: Welcome here, don't hesitate to take [the tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need. While it is appreciable that you found an answer that fulfill your question, it is usually good practice to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer. If an answer is already accepted, users might be less inclined to answer to your question, and you might miss something useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it is entirely possible to enchant sticks in Minecraft. Just place them in an anvil and enchant them using an enchanted book of you desired enchantment.

You can actually enchant any item in Minecraft in this way.

Whether or not the enchantments will work or not is dependent on what enchantment you selected, and what item you chose to enchant.

Comment: This is not true of Bedrock Edition. Actually, only specific items can be enchanted. See [Enchanting](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Enchanting#Anvil_combinations).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to enchant sticks in vanilla Minecraft Bedrock. You can get enchanted sticks from [loot tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/introductiontoloottables), but you cannot get them without behavior packs.